# make an image of pivot table

Tags: python, data-science, visualization

i have a pivot table

[image]

and i want to make an image of this pivot table in this manner

[image]

the colors are for each label

how do i create the latter image? I am working on jupyter notebook.

Comment: Check Plotly Tables https://plotly.com/python/table/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.